# How to subtract 2 timestamp (one as a date, other in HH24:MI format) and get the result in HH24:MI format in OracleSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns, Start_time and SLA.

Start time updates for each day and is in a date format e.g., 01-Jun-2021 19:15:38

SLA column is having fixed HH24MI as 2010

I want 1915 - 2010 to be -00:55 (as in HH24MI format)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'HH24')||TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'MI'))-2010,'0000') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Above will give the result as -0095 but I want it to be -00:55

Comment: @garymyers - I looked a few times at the thread you linked this one to, and I don't see anywhere where they show how to present the result as an interval hour to minute (especially one that may be negative). Care to enlighten us?

Comment: It was a use TIMESTAMPs as TIMESTAMP maths returns INTERVALs and you use the EXTRACT to get the components from the INTERVAL. It was explained very well in the linked question but someone removed that link and contributed nothing to the discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `start_time` as a `DATE` data type and the `sla` as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  start_time DATE,
  sla        INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
);
```

Then your data would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( start_time, sla ) VALUES (
  TO_DATE('01-Jun-2021 19:15:38', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'),
  INTERVAL '20:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND
);
```

And, to find the difference, you can use:

```sql
SELECT start_time,
       sla,
       (start_time - TRUNC(start_time)) DAY TO SECOND - sla AS difference
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

> | START_TIME | SLA | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-06-01 19:15:38 | +00 20:10:00.000000 | -000000000 00:54:22.000000000 |

If you want the output as a formatted string, rather than as an interval, then:

```sql
SELECT start_time,
       sla,
       CASE WHEN difference < INTERVAL '0' HOUR THEN '-' END
       || TO_CHAR( ABS( EXTRACT( HOUR FROM difference ) ), 'FM00' )
       || TO_CHAR( ABS( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM difference ) ), 'FM00' )
         AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT start_time,
         sla,
         (start_time - TRUNC(start_time)) DAY TO SECOND - sla AS difference
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which outputs:

> | START_TIME | SLA | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-06-01 19:15:38 | +00 20:10:00.000000 | -0054 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5a747168bbe742065bee3bb9a03e895)*

Comment: Nice use for intervals. You might even add the result as a virtual column i.e. `target_completion generated always as (start_time + sla)`.